# Ceiling Func prior to go1.10

Tags: go

I require a custom 'Ceil' func that works like in go1.10 upwards as we are on v1.9 (obv wont be as performant but thats ok)
e.g
`Ceil(0.33) = 1.00`

I have seen some general nearest int roundings solutions, however, wondering if anyone has implemented an equiv 'Ceil' func for v1.9 as a work around?

Comment: Why would it not be as performant? Especially since you can literally copy the exact same function from Go 1.10's standard library.

Comment: I'm sure many people have, but it's so simple that probably no one bothered to make a package: `func Ceil(f float64) float64 { return -math.Floor(-f) }`

Comment: The release of Go1.11 is imminent. When that happens, Go1.9 will no longer be supported: Release Policy: https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html#policy Consider upgrading to Go1.10 or Go1.11.

Answer (score 0):

Since Go is open source, you can just use their code directly: https://golang.org/src/math/floor.go?s=720:748#L26

I have looked into the code and extracted all the bits and pieces into [this little program](https://play.golang.org/p/l4ZJ5wAuYAU) for you:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ceil(1.5))
    fmt.Println(ceil(0.5))
    fmt.Println(ceil(0.0))
    fmt.Println(ceil(-0.5))
    fmt.Println(ceil(-1.5))
}

func ceil(x float64) float64 {
    return -floor(-x)
}

func floor(x float64) float64 {
    if x == 0 || isNaN(x) || isInf(x, 0) {
        return x
    }
    if x < 0 {
        d, fract := modf(-x)
        if fract != 0.0 {
            d = d + 1
        }
        return -d
    }
    d, _ := modf(x)
    return d
}

func isNaN(f float64) (is bool) {
    return f != f
}

func isInf(f float64, sign int) bool {
    return sign >= 0 && f > maxFloat64 || sign <= 0 && f < -maxFloat64
}

func modf(f float64) (int float64, frac float64) {
    if f < 1 {
        switch {
        case f < 0:
            int, frac = modf(-f)
            return -int, -frac
        case f == 0:
            return f, f
        }
        return 0, f
    }

    x := float64bits(f)
    e := uint(x>>shift)&mask - bias

    if e < 64-12 {
        x &^= 1<<(64-12-e) - 1
    }
    int = float64frombits(x)
    frac = f - int
    return
}

const (
    maxFloat64 = 1.797693134862315708145274237317043567981e+308
    mask       = 0x7FF
    shift      = 64 - 11 - 1
    bias       = 1023
)

func float64bits(f float64) uint64 {
    return *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&f))
}

func float64frombits(b uint64) float64 {
    return *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
}
```